# How do I read a midi file, change its instrument, and write it back?

Tags: python, ruby, perl, midi

I want to parse an already existing .mid file, change its instrument, from 'acoustic grand piano' to 'violin' for example, and save it back or as another .mid file.

From what I saw in the documentation, the instrument gets altered with a `program_change` or `patch_change` directive but I cannot find any library that does this in MIDI files that exist already. They all seem to support it only MIDI files created from scratch.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you just need the [header format](http://faydoc.tripod.com/formats/mid.htm)?

Comment: I have searched for any library in Perl and Python capable of doing what I'm asking and I've found none. It seems it's more difficult than I originally thought. As for the header, I was hoping not having to edit the binary manually.

Comment: "From what I saw in the documentation..." The documentation for what?

Comment: MIDI's specification and the documentation of the libraries that do MIDI manipulation/editing.

Comment: Have you looked at [midilib](https://github.com/jimm/midilib)? It seems offer what you're looking for.

Comment: I can't see how to do that for an already existing midi file. Also, I would prefer a Python or Perl solution as I'm not versed in Ruby.

Comment: Bump, anyone knows how to do this? It's driving me nuts.

Comment: the MIDI::Simple module on cpan may be worth a look

Comment: Already checked that out, can't figure it out if it's possible at all..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [music21 library](http://web.mit.edu/music21/) (plugging my own system, hope that's okay).  If there are patches defined in the parts, do:

```
from music21 import converter,instrument # or import *
s = converter.parse('/Users/cuthbert/Desktop/oldfilename.mid')

for el in s.recurse():
    if 'Instrument' in el.classes: # or 'Piano'
        el.activeSite.replace(el, instrument.Violin())

s.write('midi', '/Users/cuthbert/Desktop/newfilename.mid')
```

or if there are no patch changes currently defined:

```
from music21 import converter,instrument # or import *
s = converter.parse('/Users/cuthbert/Desktop/oldfilename.mid')

for p in s.parts:
    p.insert(0, instrument.Violin())

s.write('midi', '/Users/cuthbert/Desktop/newfilename.mid')
```

Answer (score 5):

The [`MIDI`](https://metacpan.org/module/MIDI) package will do this for you, but the exact approach depends on the original contents of the midi file.

A midi file consists of one or more tracks, and each track is a sequence of *events* on any of sixteen channels, such as *Note Off*, *Note On*, *Program Change* etc. The last of these will change the instrument assigned to a channel, and that is what you need to change or add.

Without any Program Change events at all, a channel will use program number (voice number) zero, which is an acoustic grand piano. If you want to change the instrument for such a channel then all you need to do is add a new Program Change event for this channel at the beginning of the track.

However if a channel already has a Program Change event then adding a new one at the beginning will have no effect because it is immediately overridden by the pre-existing one. In this case you will have to *change* the parameters of the existing event to use the instrument that you want.

Things could be even more complicated if there are originally several Program Change events for a channel, meaning that the instrument changes throughout the track. This is unusual, but if you come across a file like this you will have to decide how you want to change it.

Supposing you have a very simple midi file with a single track, one channel, and no existing Program Change events. This program creates a new `MIDI::Opus` object from the file, accesses the list of tracks (with only a single member), and takes a reference to the list of the first track's events. Then a new Program Change event (this module calls it `patch_change`) for channel 0 is *unshifted* onto the beginning of the event list. The new event has a program number of 40 - violin - so this channel will now be played with a violin instead of a piano.

With multiple tracks, multiple channels, and existing Program Change events the task becomes more complex, but the principle is the same - decide what needs to be done and alter the list of events as necessary.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use MIDI;

my $opus = MIDI::Opus->new( { from_file => 'song.mid' } );

my $tracks = $opus->tracks_r;
my $track0_events = $tracks->[0]->events_r;

unshift @$track0_events, ['patch_change', 0, 0, 40];
$opus->write_to_file('newsong.mid');
```

Comment: Borodin thank you for the answer, I appreciate it. The midi file is simple (with 2 tracks I think). Unfortunately, for some reason, the script isn't working. I get the same midi file as output (piano). Here are two .mid files to test it out. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/109180167/sound.mid  https://dl.dropbox.com/u/109180167/sound2.mid

Comment: How much help do you need? Can you debug Perl? The problem is likely to be, as I said that there is already a program change in the tracks so adding one at the beginning makes no difference.

Comment: `sound.mid` has three tracks. The first is a tempo track and contains no notes, so putting a program change at the beginning will have no effect. The second and third tracks both have a program change (to voice zero - piano) as their first events, so you need to change or delete these events or put your own program change after thwm. `sound2.mid` has just one track and no program change event, so it plays using the default voice zero. However it uses channel 15 for some reason, so you need to add a program change event on channel 15. Repatching channel 0 has no effect because it never plays.