# Music21: Get all Notes per Instrument from a MIDI File

Tags: python, midi, music21

I am parsing a MIDI file as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448380/how-do-i-read-a-midi-file-change-its-instrument-and-write-it-back). My code looks like this:

```
from music21 import converter,instrument # or import *
file = converter.parse('sample.mid')
components = []
for element in file.recurse():
    components.append(element)
```

The `components` list now contains data as follows:

```
<music21.stream.Score 0x7f50314ca390>,
<music21.stream.Part 0x7f50314caf10>,
<music21.instrument.Instrument Acoustic Guitar>,
<music21.instrument.Instrument Acoustic Guitar>,
<music21.tempo.MetronomeMark allegro moderato Quarter=130.0>,
<music21.meter.TimeSignature 4/4>,
<music21.note.Note E>,
<music21.note.Note B>,
<music21.note.Note E>,
<music21.note.Note B>,
<music21.note.Note E>,
<music21.note.Rest rest>,
.
.
.
<music21.chord.Chord B3 E3>,
<music21.chord.Chord B3 E3>,
<music21.chord.Chord B3 E3>,
<music21.chord.Chord B3 E3>,
<music21.chord.Chord B3 E3>,
<music21.chord.Chord B3 E3>,
<music21.chord.Chord D4 F#3>,
<music21.chord.Chord D4 F#3>,
<music21.chord.Chord D4 F#3>,
.
.
.
<music21.stream.Part 0x7f50309b99d0>,
<music21.instrument.Instrument Electric Guitar>,
<music21.instrument.Instrument Electric Guitar>,
<music21.meter.TimeSignature 4/4>,
<music21.note.Rest rest>,
<music21.note.Note E>,
<music21.note.Note F#>,
<music21.note.Note G>,
<music21.note.Note A>,
<music21.note.Note G>,
<music21.note.Note E>,
<music21.note.Rest rest>,
```

My aim is to **segregate notes according to each instrument** which is listed in a tag like `<music21.instrument.Instrument Electric Guitar>`. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll want the `instrument.partitionByInstrument()` function, which will separate your stream into different parts according to the instrument.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I really appreciate it. However I am encountering the an error while executing the following:

instruments = instrument.partitionByInstrument(file)

StreamException: the object (<music21.tempo.MetronomeMark allegro moderato Quarter=130.0>, id()=140306780864464) is already found in this Stream (<music21.stream.Part Acoustic Guitar>, id()=140306889172688)

Comment: I request for any suggestions on this